# My HTML5 video's used more than 200GB bandwidth in two days

Tags: wordpress, html, video

I used two html 5 video's on my website  the size of the first video was 20MB en the size of the second video was 42MB. They are on outplay and I used this code to implement it

```
<video controls autoplay loop poster="http://www.bgc.nl/augmax/wp-content/themes/augmax/images/343018071.png" id="bgvid">
    <source src="343018071.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/augmax/wp-content/themes/augmax/videos/343018071.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Within two days only this page used more than 200GB of bandwidth even so that our resellers account got suspended. I have no clue how two video's could use so much bandwidth. Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this problem that it won't use so much bandwidth?

I also installed WP Cache, do you think that could help?

I asked my hoster and he told me that more than 95% of the 200GB came from loading those two video's. All help is highly appreciated!

Ps. The video aren't visible on the site due this problem.

Comment: Why don't you upload these videos on youtube and embed these vídeos in your website? There are multiple reasons to not host your own vídeos one of these reasons is bandwidth you can read more about it [here](https://www.wp101.com/10-reasons-why-you-should-never-host-your-own-videos/).

Comment: Consider disabling autoplay until the user explicitly chooses to play the video. Otherwise, host the videos on a CDN or YouTube as the previous commenter suggests.

Comment: Let's do the math: 200GB / (20MB + 42MB) ≈ 3300 visits. Well 3.3k visitors looks OK. Check your google analytics (or what ever you're using for analytics) and if the number of visitors is close to 3k then mystery solved. If the number is higher then probably it's the caching doing its work. If the number is lower than look at the server logs and see where all these requests are comming from. Maybe it's a rouge crawler or a DoS attack.